# Number of records with a specific value

Tags: sql, django

I need your advice with one sql request. I have two tables in django models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    finish_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Code(models.Model):
    code_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
```

One game can include a few code with same code_text. I want to get total count of game which include every correct code (something like 'code_text' - 'total count of game which include this code and this code was correct') but can only total number every correct code per game. My code below

```
SELECT backend_code.code_text, COUNT(backend_game.name) 
FROM backend_code 
JOIN backend_code_game ON backend_code.id=backend_code_game.code_id 
JOIN backend_game ON backend_game.id=backend_code_game.game_id 
WHERE backend_code.correct=true
AND backend_code.code_text IN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT backend_code.code_text FROM backend_code 
    JOIN backend_code_game ON backend_code.id=backend_code_game.code_id
    JOIN backend_game ON backend_game.id=backend_code_game.game_id
    WHERE backend_code.correct=true)
GROUP BY backend_code.code_text 
ORDER BY COUNT(backend_game.name) 
DESC;
```

How i can do this? Thanks

For example:
Code table

```
  id   | code_text | correct | player_name 
--------+-----------+---------+-------------
 894237 | flow      | f       | legizi
 894236 | over      | t       | beard_beer
 894235 | over      | t       | R.A.V.E.
 894234 | over      | t       | Rinhos
 894233 | over      | f       | Warner
 894232 | stack     | t       | ЛедENец
 894231 | stack     | f       | диманыч 001
 894230 | stack     | t       | snowshika
 894229 | stack     | t       | -=tink=-
```

Game table

```
 id  |  name  | finish_date 
------+--------+-------------
 1176 | game 1 | 2019-12-27
 1175 | game 2 | 2019-12-27
 1174 | game 3 | 2019-12-27
```

Code_game table

```
code_id | game_id 
---------+---------
  894237 |    1174
  894236 |    1174
  894235 |    1174
  894234 |    1174
  894233 |    1175
  894232 |    1174
  894231 |    1175
  894230 |    1176
  894229 |    1176
```

Expected result:

```
code_text | game_count 
-----------+------------
stack      | 2
over       | 1
flow       | 0
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, Could you provide some data to illustrate what you want to achieve? It would also be helpful to have a full description of your tables as your query mentions columns that you haven't mentioned in your question. The more detail you provide in your question, the better your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @BarryPiccinni try explain in question, sorry for my english :)
Approximate algorithm: 1) get correct code 2) if code in game and code is correct (no matter hwo many it is found in this game) then +1 to counter and check the codes for next game

Comment: @ErgiNushi PostgreSQL 9.5.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `code_text` in the `code` table, you want the count of games where it was `correct`.

You could use aggregation and a conditional `count(distinct ...)`. Assuming that you use Postgres (which the syntax of your question tends to indicate):

```
select
    c.code_text,
    count(distinct cg.game_id) filter(where c.correct) game_count
from code_game cg
inner join code c on c.id = cg.code_id 
group by c.code_text
order by game_count desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d5a2eee2be14b3b5ed19be7fa768940b)**:

```
code_text | game_count
:-------- | ---------:
stack     |          2
over      |          1
flow      |          0
```

Comment: Although this works I am not sure why you would use Raw SQL when working with Django? (Unless, of course, it is the only solution)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to generate a resulting queryset containing all `Code` objects marked as correct and the number of `Game` objects each `Code` object is assigned to.

For this you could use Django aggregations as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

For instance like this

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Code.objects.filter(correct=True).annotate(
         game_count = Count('game')
     )

for c in qs:
    print(c.code_text, c.game_count)
```

**Update**

After seeing your ammendments I understood better what you are aiming at. This is one solution utilizing Django's ORM:

```
qs = Code.games.through.objects.filter(code__correct=True)\
            .values('code__code_text', 'game').distinct()\
                .values('code__code_text').order_by().annotate(count=Count('game', distinct=True))

for q in qs:
     print(q)
```

Gives you the output

```
{'code__code_text': 'over', 'count': 1}
{'code__code_text': 'stack', 'count': 2}
```